# Undefined variable: query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, codeigniter-2

I'm getting an error Undefined variable: query. I've been searching through the codeigniter forums and here for a solution but nothing seemed to work. If you can find what I'm doing wrong here I would greatly appreciate it.

Message: Undefined variable: query
Filename: views/display.php
Line Number: 3

Controller

```
function index() {
$this->load->model('mdl_tasks');
$data['query'] = $this->mdl_tasks->get('priority');
$this->load->view('display');
}
}
```

Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mdl_tasks extends CI_Model {


function __construct()
{
// Call the Model constructor
parent::__construct();
}
function get($order_by) {
$this->db->order_by($order_by);
$query = $this->db->get('tasks');
return $query;
}
}
```

View

```
<h1>Your tasks</h1>
<?php
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
echo "<h2>".$row->title."</h2";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to include `$data` here:

```
   $this->load->view('display', $data);
```